# Bug on Xcode 8.0, or frameworks (in red) not loading?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, alamofire

**TL;DR**: *Foundation.framework appears in red afters doing pod install. That is solved by creating an iPhoneOS9.3.SDK folder on /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs but another error results from that.*

I have Xcode 8.0 (8A218a) and I'm trying to use Alamofire library through Cocoapods 1.1.0.rc.2 (pre). 
I also had this same problem while Xcode 8 was still in Beta, and after some tries I haven't figure out how to solve it.

Basically, I successfully init and install Alamofire pod, I'm able to import Alamofire and Foundation into my project and also run it or build into my device, you can see that below:
[image: Importing]

But there is this thing that bugs me off: On Pods/Frameworks/iOS the Foundation.framework file always appears in red... You can see that here:
[image]

First of all I don't understand why it appears in red because I can import Foundation and build the app... Do you think this is a bug or is something that I need to fix?

While trying to fix it I searched about it on the internet and I've tried most common solutions like: pod update, delete all pod files and make pod install again, change Xcode developer path, update to the newest version of Xcode and Cocoapods, I even made an hard reset to my Mac but nothing seems to work...

As you can notice in the first image, when Foundation.framework is selected, we can see the path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/**iPhoneOS9.3.SDK**/... By going into that directory, I could check that I don't have a folder for iPhoneOS9.3.SDK, only for iPhoneOS.sdk and iPhoneOS10.sdk, as you see below:
[image: SDKs folder]

This is when I thought: I just need to duplicate the iPhoneOS10.sdk and change the name to iPhoneOS9.3.sdk. I did that and in fact when I open the project the framework is not in red anymore, you can see below.
However, after doing this, I'm not able to build the app into a device anymore, I get this error: 
[image: error]

I feel like I've tried most of the things out there and they didn't help, I either get a red framework that allows me to build the project into my device, or a proper framework that doesn't allow me to build into my device... 
Do you have any idea how I can solve this, or should I just ignore it and work with Foundation.framework in red?

You can find the project [here](https://github.com/smbss/RainyShinyCloudy) and a Gist file with the error [here](https://gist.github.com/smbss/5624ce1a2e719f8d27feff7a2196b449).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't change the name of SDK folder in any case i think,as it has a close link with IDE.
I had the same problem just now.And resolved by changing the path of the 'red framework'.because the path shows 'SDK IOS9' before.So i set the framework location 'relative to SDK' and choose the right framework location manually.and it works temporarily.

[image]

I guess the reason is that i updated to Xcode 8,but my coacopods is still old version,so it set the location with IOS9 which cause this problem.

Comment: Thank you, hope you fixed your problem too! I believe I ended up solving it by dragging the framework to the project itself.